# Change 2 values in a string

Tags: string, t-sql, increment

I have the following string `2014/15` passed as a parameter to my procedure and I need to increment the `4` and `5` by `1` so I end up with `2015/16`.

Obviously the string is a `VARCHAR` so I can't use any normal arithmetic functions, nor `DATEADD`. The parameter must be passed in as is and I must derive a year above and a year below as well as using the parameter.

To simplify, if you feed in `2014/15` then in my SP I will need to use `2013/14`, `2014/15` and `2015/16` in various parts or the SP all derived from that 1 string.

Comment: Do you expect to be retired when "2098/99" pops up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you can do is this:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @date = '2014/15'

SELECT 
    CAST(
        CAST(
            SUBSTRING(@date, 0, CHARINDEX('/', @date)) 
        AS INTEGER) + 1 
    AS VARCHAR(4))
    + '/' 
    + RIGHT(
      CAST(
          CAST(
              SUBSTRING(@date, 0, CHARINDEX('/', @date)) 
          AS INTEGER) + 2
      AS VARCHAR(4))
  , 2)
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/43556) with how the code works.

The first part of the query will return the year `2014` incremented by 1.

It will then append a slash to it. Using the first date again (2014), which is extracted in the same manner, I increment it by 2. I then convert this value to a VARCHAR value so I can do string operations on it ([RIGHT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) function).

I then use the [RIGHT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) function to extract the last 2 characters, which I append to my original string.

Answer (score 2):

Here, this might help you:

```
DECLARE @Input varchar(10)
SET @Input = '2014/15'
DECLARE @First INT, @Second INT
SET @First = SUBSTRING(@Input, 1, CHARINDEX('/', @Input) - 1)
SET @Second = SUBSTRING(@Input, CHARINDEX('/', @Input) + 1, LEN(@Input))
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (@First + 1)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (@Second + 1))
```

Basically it pulls the two components which are separated by the forward slash character `/` into `INT` variables which you can increment or decrement as needed, and then it converts those result values back to `VARCHAR` and puts that back together with the separator character.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's very nice but I will be using the answer as part of a larger variable SET and my SSMS doesn't seem to like referencing the value of 1 variable to set another in the declare section though I can't figure out why

Comment: If I do the following

DECLARE
Var1 AS VARCHAR = 'abc',
Var2 AS VARCAHR = Var1+'def'

I get
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "Var1".

Comment: "Var2 AS VARCAHR = Var1+'def'" is not valid syntax.  You can't do that.  Either way, did I answer your question?  If so, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following but it isn't particularly elegant

```
SUBSTRING(@Date, 1, 3)+CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@Date, 4,1)AS INT)+1 AS VARCHAR)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@Date, 6, 1)+CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@Date, 7,1)AS INT)+1 AS VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following uses the documented implicit type conversions ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).) to convert the substrings to integers. Note that it does not use `CharIndex` to locate the solidus ("/"), but *assumes* that the column has exactly the format you specified: four digits, solidus, two digits.

```
declare @Sample as Char(7) = '2014/15';
select Cast( Left( @Sample, 4 ) + 1 as Char(4) ) + '/' +
  Cast( Right( @Sample, 2 ) + 1 as Char(2) );
```